# Rename [persona-2-ep] → [persona-2-eternal-punishment]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

With our 35 character tag limit, the tag for *[Persona 2: Eternal Punishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persona_2:_Eternal_Punishment)* should be expanded as follows:

- [persona-2-ep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/persona-2-ep) → [persona-2-eternal-punishment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/persona-2-eternal-punishment)

This will make it consistent with the other game in the series, [persona-2-innocent-sin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/persona-2-innocent-sin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
updating post history, 4 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 4 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [persona-2-eternal-punishment] and [persona-2-ep] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
4 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym persona-2-ep -> persona-2-eternal-punishment was approved!
```